# Javascript Validations Remove border color of each field one by one when it is filled

Tags: javascript, validation

Here, i am getting the problem to change the fields border color (after validation message) to its (up on filling the text-input) original color.

It is coming like as when i press the next button all the fields color changed to red. Up on filling the field i want to remove this color to white.

Next:- I have to show the error message with the border color also.
e.g. for all fields there should be message like (Incomplete).

```
if(oldIndex==0)
{
    var $emailv   = document.getElementById('user_email').value;
    var $passwordd = document.getElementById('chatinput2').value;
    var $cpassw   = document.getElementById('chatinput3').value;
    var fields    = document.getElementsByClassName("vikass");

    if($emailv=="" && $passwordd == "" && $cpassw == "")
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        {
            if(fields[i].value="" )
            {
                fields[i].style.border="2px solid red";

            }
            else
            {
                fields[i].style.border="";
            }
        }

    }
    else if($emailv=="")
    {

        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML="<img src='/APPEX/appex/wp-content/themes/jobs/images/incorrect_icon.png'> Please Enter the Email";
    }
    else if($passwordd==""){

        document.getElementById('user_pass').innerHTML="<img src='/APPEX/appex/wp-content/themes/jobs/images/incorrect_icon.png'> Please Enter the Password";
    }
    else if(cpassw=""){

        document.getElementById('u_c_pass').innerHTML="<img src='/APPEX/appex/wp-content/themes/jobs/images/incorrect_icon.png'> Please Enter the Confirm Password";
    }
    else if($passwordd != $cpassw){

        document.getElementById('u_c_pass').innerHTML="<img src='/APPEX/appex/wp-content/themes/jobs/images/incorrect_icon.png'> Password don not match";
    }
    else{
        if (index >= 0 && index < state.stepCount && !(options.forceMoveForward && index < state.currentIndex))
        {
            var anchor = getStepAnchor(wizard, index),
                parent = anchor.parent(),
                isDisabled = parent.hasClass("disabled");

            // Enable the step to make the anchor clickable!
            parent._enableAria();
            anchor.click();

            // An error occured
            if (oldIndex === state.currentIndex && isDisabled)
            {
                // Disable the step again if current index has not changed; prevents click action.
                parent._enableAria(false);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u show us the html and the css ?

Comment: Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljmj/mrxnqaph/